# How to Add a Filter in CustomAuthorizeAttribute Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, authorize-attribute

I want to have a filter on my custom authorize attribute but I don't have idea how to add it in my code. I want it like this.

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin, Supervisor, SystemUser")]
[CustomAuthorize(Users="Kenneth,John")]
[CustomAuthorize(Customfilter="Update, View")]
```

This is my customauthorize, what to add in my code to have a filter?

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext(); // my entity  

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
            {
                return;
            }

            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User).Identity).IsAuthenticated)
            {

                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource")
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
        }

        private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.ToList();

            if (user != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use customauthorization like below

```
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string Roles { get; set; }
        private string Customfilter { get; set; }
        private string Users { get; set; }
        public CustomAuthorize(string roles, string users,string Customfilter)
        {
            Roles = roles;
            Users = users;
            Customfilter = Customfilter
        }
       //Your default code here
       ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext(); // my entity  

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User).Identity).IsAuthenticated)
        {

            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource")
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
    }

    private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.ToList();

        if (user != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then? How will the Users, Roles and Customfilter will work? How will they filter? Also, does it mean the value of this 

[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Admin, Supervisor, SystemUser") will be pass automatically in the customauthorize?
Thanks!

Comment: The values that has been passed from method will be available in the class. you can use your logic to check like if method says role 'Admin', does the use logged in has that role if yes authorize else leave it out

Comment: public CustomAuthorize(string roles, string users,string Customfilter)
        {
            Roles = roles;
            Users = users;
            Customfilter = Customfilter
        } Is this tha passing of value from attribute?

Comment: Yes, this will pass the value to CustomAuthorize when you put on top of method [CustomAuthorize("Admin, Supervisor, SystemUser")]

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me!!